# Visual Studio NuGet Package removes itself after reloading (Unity)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, nuget, system.reactive

so I imported a library in my assembly project. Now I need to add some packages from the nuget launcher. As I install them my code gets fine, the namespace is found, and the package appears in my reference.[image: before pic]
But in Unity theres still a error saying namespace not found. If I click on the Error the VS Project reloads and removes my added package -> namespace not found . . .
[image: After reopening]

The package still is installed but I cant add the reference to my project.

[image: installed packages]

It's about the using System.Reactive.Linq and using System.Reactive.Subjects
Then I call the Observable class and create a Subject.

searching for help

greetings

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solutions.

1. The target framework library of Unity does not support the framework library of .Net. Please click File→Build Settings→Player. You can find the Api Compatibility Level. You could try to change from .NET Standard 2.0 to .NET 4.x.

[image]

2. There is no problem with the Unity target framework library and the version of Unity, it still has some errors. You need to find the corresponding dll file according to the missing assembly, and then put it in Unity's Plugins folder.